# Stopping jQuery animations from queuing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

EDIT 17/2/14: I've tried to use the .toggle JQuery function to work around this but it doesn't seem to be working with my current set-up. I've been keeping an eye on it in Chrome's dev console and it does literally nothing when it tries to execute. Here's the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".remove").toggle(function() { 
                 $($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                  },
                   function() { 
                 $($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                });
});
```

OLD:

> I'm trying to get a unique tooltip to appear for each of the imagemap areas that are > hovered, however when it comes to animating them to fade or slide in, they either queue and animate one after another, clipping behind the imagemap if a lot are hovered at once, or none animate in at all.
>
> Here's my code. I'd rather not change the mark-up:
>
> Hovering over: 1
>      Hovering over: 2
>      Hovering over: 3
>      Hovering over: 4
>      Hovering over: 5
>
> $('.remove').mouseover(function(){
>      $($(this).attr("data-ref")).show();
>      });
>
> $('.remove').mouseout(function(){
>      $($(this).attr("data-ref")).hide();
>      });

Comment: Try `$($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop(true).fadeIn();` and `$($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop(true).fadeOut();`

Comment: I still appear to be getting the same issues with several divs fading in one after the other without a break between animations playing out, or none of them playing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.stop(true,true](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$($(this).data("ref")).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
```

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[.fadein()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: This seemed to work the best. I'm still getting animations stacking up but I'll try and play around with the stop values and see if I can get something working.

Comment: Also: .data("ref") didn't seem to work. Does .data insert the hyphen as per my attribute? I changed it back to .attr("data-href") and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
$('.remove').mouseover(function(){
$($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop();
$($(this).attr("data-ref")).show();
});

$('.remove').mouseout(function(){
$($(this).attr("data-ref")).stop();
$($(this).attr("data-ref")).hide();
});
```